# Why shouldn't we just run Redis inside Kubernetes instead of Elasticache?

Tags: kubernetes, redis, amazon-elasticache

AWS Elasticache is expensive.
However, we have lots of extra RAM on our Kubernetes cluster.

For what reasons would we not just install Redis on Kubernetes instead of using Elasticache.

Comment: For one - PersistentVolumeClaims are complicated. But try it... What errors do you get? You're paying for more than "just Redis" with any cloud offering. You also will have access to support engineers, for example, and more seamless upgrades and backups